# Desktop Won't Refresh, Files on The Desktop Don't Open Correctly

Tags: 20.04, icons, launcher, desktop-icons

I've had the following issues since installing 20.04.

If I download (via browser) files to the desktop or any folder on the desktop, about half of the time they never appear. Either on the desktop or in the file manager.

If I open images files on the desktop in GIMP, after about 30 seconds GIMP will crash/close.

The icons I can see on the desktop don't always correspond to the ones I can see in the file manager. The file manager shows the actual files. The desktop often shows icons that have been deleted.

Any ideas where I could even start looking for the problem?

Comment: I would just not save files to the desktop. That's what `~/Downloads/` is for. Alternatively you could use another folder.